# Safe working technique; four axle stands

Tags: safety

I would never dream of going under a car without it adequately supported; axle stands plus wheels, if removed, laid under the sills (rockers).

I have a full set of brake lines plus a serious amount of welding to do on a car that’s currently next in the queue to come into the garage.  Not to mention the fact I’ve got to drop the suspension off it.

All of this would be considerably easier if I could get the whole thing into the air.  I’ve worked with others who have supported a car on four stands with all four wheels removed but it isn’t something I’ve ever done myself.  I have a distant memory of someone once telling me that it wasn’t safe but that may have been folklore as much as actual technically sound advice.

So, my question: four stands, is it considered a safe working practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's absolutely safe *as long as the jack stands are placed correctly*. What is "placed correctly"? That depends on the vehicle which they will be under. You have to use good placement, but they are safe, no doubt. Placement is everything. Well, hard, level ground helps as well.

Consider when people use a two post lift with four pads. You place the lifting pads under the vehicle at the proper points and lift the vehicle. Nobody thinks twice who has used these and places the pads correctly. Why is that? Because it's safe. There's nothing different here other than the vehicle doesn't go up/down with the supports.

Comment: Also make sure the stands are good quality with a "wide" base for stability.

Comment: And that the flooring that they’re standing on is level, steady and strong enough to handle the loads.